# How to change if statement from alert to text

Tags: javascript, input

How would I instead of have the if statement come up as an alert, have it appear as text on my page. Thanks

```
 document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {

        if (document.getElementById("ask").value=="how tall are the pyramids") {

            alert ("146.5 meters");

            } else if (document.getElementById("ask").value == "how tall is the gateway arch") {

alert("630 feet");

         } else if (document.getElementById("ask").value == "how tall is the empire state building") {

         alert("6900 feet");
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("idOfResultDivHere").innerHTML = "146.5 metres";`

Comment: make an element in the html to display a text, say span or something you like. Then taking the span's id you can set the text to it that you want as document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 metres"

Comment: what is id="ask" element is div  or is input

Comment: oh sorry its an input

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood, but it sounds like you want to display the value in an html element rather than alerting the value. See the below example

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var val = document.getElementById("ask").value;
  var answer = "I don't know!";
  if (val == "how tall are the pyramids")
    answer = "146.5 meters";
  else if (val == "how tall is the gateway arch")
    answer = "630 feet";
  else if (val == "how tall is the empire state building")
    answer = "6900 feet";
  document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = answer;
}
```

And in the html, add an answer element like so

```
<p id="answer"></p>
```

See [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPwyoV)

Comment: That didn't do anything but make the alert not come up :(

Comment: @MaxR I've created a CodePen and linked it in my post. The code I provided works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add another element to your page that can display the results.

In the demo below I have added a `span` element and set the `id` attribute to `answer`.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick=function(){
var Q = document.getElementById("ask").value;
var A = document.getElementById("answer");
var Result = "Ask another?";
  if (Q=="how tall are the pyramids"){
    Result="146.5 meters";
  }else if(Q=="how tall is the gateway arch"){
    Result="630 feet";
  }else if(Q == "how tall is the empire state building"){
    Result="6900 feet";
  }
  A.innerHTML = Result;
}
```

```html
<span id="answer"></span><br/>
<input type="text" id="ask" />
<button type="button" id="button">Ask</button>
```

If you don't understand any of the above source code, please leave a comment below.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 document.getElementById("ask").value
```

to

```
document.getElementById("ask").innerHTML
```

or

```
document.getElementById("ask").innerText
```